# Type cannot be serialized

Tags: apex, json

our org use a managed package PCK1. This package has the following class:

```
global class Parent {
    global class Child {
        global string field1;
        global string field2;
        global string field3;
}
```

We serialize the object as json like below:

```
PCK1.Parent.Child obj = new PCK1.Parent.Child();
obj.field1 = 'test 1';
obj.field2 = 'test 2';
obj.field3 = 'test 3';

JSON.serialize(obj);
```

This code works fine when PCK1.Parent class is using API>59 otherwise we got the following error: **Type cannot be serialized**

I tried to check API changelogs/update but nothing special related to this issue.

Anyone has an idea about this ?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

This almost certainly relates to the [@JsonAccess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_JsonAccess.htm) annotation and the release updates related to it (e.g. [this one](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_vf_jsonaccess_annotation_ru.htm&release=248&type=5)).

This annotation enables or disables use of JSON serialization for managed package classes outside the package.